# How to get an item from list

Tags: python-3.x

Am trying to get the required item from list(looks like list of dict). would like to know if there is a better way to do this. I feel have used too many split to get the Gender value.

```
>>> record = ['{"Name": "Jack", "Gender": "Male"}']
>>>
>>> type(record)
<class 'list'>
>>>
>>> for item in record:
...     Gen = item.split(",")[1].split()[1].rstrip("}")
...
>>> print(Gen)
"Male"
>>>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you not just make a dict by removing the single-quotes and the bracket? Alternatively, using `ast.literal_eval` to interpret the string as a dict is probably the easiest method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there, is a list with one string element which is a JSON formatted object (dictionary). So:

```
import json
record = ['{"Name": "Jack", "Gender": "Male"}']
print(json.loads(record[0])["Gender"])  # Male
```

This is however a strange input structure. If you have control over how this list came to be, you should change it, and make sure that you either avoid that dictionary to be encoded as JSON, or -- if you received it as JSON -- parse that JSON at an earlier stage -- before it gets wrapped in that list.